# how to set price format thousandsSeparator in tradingview

Tags: tradingview-api

how to set price format thousandsSeparator in tradingview?
This is a document, but I can’t quite understand it. Thank you for your answer:
https://www.tradingview.com/charting-library-docs/latest/api/interfaces/Broker.ISymbolValueFormatter